# Setting alternative port - what are the best practises?

Tags: port, jboss

I'm setting up a jBoss EAP Server (right now on my local machine), in a rather strict security environment.  The default port is 8080, which is also the proxy is for the network.

What port should the EAP Server be set to? [Wiki's list of known ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) is very long. This organization is quite big and there are a lot of legacy systems, I'm sure to trip over some other port already in use at so point later in development.

Comment: Ask your security administrators to nominate a port.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will have to make that request to security admins and network admins, but before I do so I'd to be able to say something like "use 90454~9, because traditionally 9040s have been used as for application servers. 9042 and 9043 are unofficial ports for Cassandra and Websphere"

Comment: Without understanding the constraints of their policy, it is near impossible to suggest anything.  Given that this port will only be used by your service, it doesn't really matter what it is provided it doesn't conflict with anything else *on the same server* - unless there is a security policy that says otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm beginning to think the problem is elsewhere. I changed the port to 9045 and the same error appeared "Web Poller found a running server at url http://localhost:9045" But netstat -aon | find /i "listening" shows nothing at 9045

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify which version you are running but I assume EAP6 (AS7).

In standalone.xml you can specify the value of the port offset:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

As you can see there are a lot of port to consider.
The 'best practice' here would be to increase the value of port-offset by 100 to not conflict with other ports used on the system. At least http, https and the management ports need to work. The other ports are dependent on your needs/uses.

So you would have http on 8180 and https on 8543.